# C++11 alternative to the Java anonymous callback class

Tags: java, c++, c++11, callback, abstract-class

I realise that the solution I have here is far from ideal with C++, so I'm asking what a proper C++ programmer would do in this situation. (C++11)

I have a `DialogBox` class, which stores a collection of buttons. At the moment I have a pure abstract inner class `DialogBox::Button` with the pure virtual function `virtual void callback() const`.

From Java I'm used to using this strategy to create and instantiate an anonymous class deriving from Button in-place which implements the callback function. Something like this:

```
db.add_button(new Button( "Button text", BUTTONTYPE ) {
    public void callback() {
        // Callback code
}});
```

which is what prompted this C++ solution.

My C++ solution therefore looks like

`dialogbox.h`

```
class DialogBox {
public:
    // Abstract class for buttons with callback functions
    class Button;

private:
    /* ...
      stuff 
     */

public:
    /* ...
      stuff 
     */
    const std::vector< unique_ptr<DialogBox::Button> >& get_buttons() const;
    void add_button( unique_ptr<DialogBox::Button>& new_button );
};


class DialogBox::Button {

private:
    /* ...
      stuff
     */

public:
    // Constructor
    Button( const string& button_text, const DialogButtonType button_type = DialogButtonType::NORMAL );

    /* ...
      stuff
     */

    // Virtual callback function
    virtual void callback() const = 0;

};
```

Usage:

```
// Instantiate
DialogBox db{ /* ... args ... */ };
// Test adding buttons
class Button1 : public DialogBox::Button {
    using DialogBox::Button::Button;
    public: void callback() const {
        // Callback code
    }
};
std::unique_ptr<DialogBox::Button> button1{ new Button1{ "Button1", DialogButtonType::ENTER } };
db.add_button( button1 );
```

This works, but it's clearly not as clean as the Java version and certainly feels like I'm shoehorning in something that C++ is not designed to do.

So, how would a C++ programmer do this? It seems conceptually right to have Button as a class (since it has internal data and its own behaviour). At the moment I'm thinking of using a lambda expression to pass in the callback function to Button's constructor, but I thought I'd get some expert opinion on the subject.

Comment: This doesnt seems like a good practice.

Comment: I realise this, which is why I've come in search of good-practice solutions.

Comment: What version of C++?  C++11 has lambda functions.

Comment: lambda and/or std::function may help.

Comment: @pathfinderelite yes, it's C++11. Do you suggest I use lambdas as described in my last paragraph?

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to recommend them, as I am not overly familiar with them myself, but on the surface, lambdas seem like a good fit.

Comment: What else does the button do?  If a button carries no more information than "what I do when I click", it doesn't have to be a class at all!

Comment: @Yakk. Right now it carries a type and some text, but I wanted to keep it extensible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++11 solution would be to have `Button` look something like this. I'm skipping the `string` and `DialogButtonType` parameters for brevity:

```
class Button {
public:
    template <typename F>
    Button(F&& f) : cb(std::forward<F>(f))
    { }

    void callback() { cb(); }

private:
    std::function<void()> cb; // type-erased functor for ANY callable
                              // that takes zero arguments
};
```

This allows you to have a container of `Button`s that do completely arbitrary things in their `callback`s - no inheritance necessary. It also allows you to great one-off buttons on the fly by providing them with an arbitrary callback functor as part of the construction process:

```
db.add_button(std::make_unique<Button>([=]{
     // arbitrary Callback code
}));
```

As a side-note, `add_button` should definitely take its `unique_ptr` argument by value, not by reference.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Should I also be returning the vector of unique_ptrs by value rather than by reference?

Comment: @JMAA By reference. You'd have to `move` it out otherwise - unless that's the semantic you want, in which case, sure, by value.

Comment: Why have a class `Button` at all?  It seems useless.  `typedef std::function<void()> Button` -- it isn't really a button, just an action to take when clicked.

Comment: @Yakk I assume the name had some significance for something?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an aggregate:

```
struct Button {
  std::string name;
  std::function<void()> on_click;
};
```

now you can `add_button({"hello", []{std::cout<<" world\n";}});`

Minimal code, minimal boilerplate.

I generally start with this kind of thing, and only add more infrastructure as needed.

Comment: This looks nicely minimal. Sorry for the noob question, but does it allow me to deal with `const` buttons and other access controls?

Comment: @jmaa The button is taken by-value, and its `const`ness means you cannot change the action/name, but not much else.